# onClick function doesn't work on first submit click

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and need some help lol. I have done a form that is supposed to disappear onClick and be replaced with a text. It works... but only after the second time I click submit. How do I make it work the first time?

```
<div class="subscribe" id="subscribe">
    <h1>SUBSCRIBE</h2>
        <p>Be in the know and sign up for our email list.</p>
    <form class="form" id="form">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" onClick="replaceForm()">
      </form>
</div>
<div id="replacement">
    <p>Thank you for signing up!</p>
</div>
```

//in js file

```
function replaceForm() {

var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("replacement").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: `form` is a link, and when you submit a form, you're navigating to a new page. Don't submit a form, if you don't want to navigate away from the current page.

Answer (score 2):

- Pass [the implicit `event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_objects) into `replaceForm` [and then call `e.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).
- Also, consider using `form.hidden = true;` instead of `form.style.display = 'none';`.

Like so:

```html
<input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="replaceForm(event)">
```

```js
function replaceForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    form.hidden = true;
    document.getElementById("replacement").style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Submit is use to submit your form data to particular URL, which get the data from form and process it further.**

i.e example : login page - after adding user name password your are sending it to backend to process the user login credential.

- **In this code snippet you are not submitting data to any location so better you use button as input type.**
- **Once you click on submit it send data to  action location but in  you have not mention action location so it will simple refresh the page with same URL.**
- <input type="button" id="submit" onClick="replaceForm()"/ >

HTML :

```
<div class="subscribe" id="subscribe">
    <h1>SUBSCRIBE</h2>
        <p>Be in the know and sign up for our email list.</p>
    <form class="form" id="form">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" required>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <input type="button" id="submit" onClick="replaceForm()">
      </form>
</div>
<div id="replacement">
    <p>Thank you for signing up!</p>
</div>





function replaceForm() {

var form = document.getElementById("form");
form.style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("replacement").style.display = "block";
}
```